# Piecewise integration not giving continuous result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

I'm trying to integrate a piecewise function symbolically and I'm ending up with discontinuities which is surprising since the help mentions that constants are determined to ensure continuity.

If I replace my constants BEFORE doing the integration, the result IS continuous.  Other posts on SO mentioned that the continuity cannot be done in the case of multiple variables, but I have tried to make it clear that only my "t" symbol is a variable.

The variable replaceConstantsBeforeIntegration can be set to True or False to determine whether the constants are replaced before or after integration.

Any ideas?  I'm a Mathematica newbie so feel free to give me any suggestions for improvement.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
replaceConstantsBeforeIntegration = False;
$Assumptions = duration1 > 0 & duration2 > 0 && t > 0;
SetAttributes[{duration1, duration2}, Constant];
jer1 = Sin[(Pi*t)/duration1] ;
jer2 = 1;
constants = {duration1 -> 6, duration2 -> 5};

jerks = {jer1, jer2};
boundaries = {t < duration1, t < duration1 + duration2};

jer = Piecewise[Transpose[{jerks, boundaries}]] /. 
   If[replaceConstantsBeforeIntegration, constants, {}];
acc = Integrate[jer, t, Assumptions -> {t \[Element] Reals}];

domain = {t, 0, duration1 + duration2} /. constants;
Plot[jer /. constants, domain, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[acc /. constants, domain, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the definite integral, not the antiderivative:

```
acc = Integrate[jer /. t -> $t, {$t, 0, t}, 
   Assumptions -> {t \[Element] Reals}];

Plot[acc /. constants, domain, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: This also works, and it's a bit faster: `acc = DSolveValue[{y'[t] == jer, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]`

Comment: Thanks!  Related follow-up question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220084/why-do-integrate-and-dsolve-dsolvevalue-yield-such-complex-expressions-for-piece