# Why do Integrate and DSolve/DSolveValue yield such complex expressions for Piecewise functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, piecewise

This code uses two different methods for integrating a very simple piecewise function but yields surprisingly complicated integrals:

```
jer1 = Sin[(Pi*t)/duration1] ;
jer2 = 1;
constants = {duration1 -> 6, duration2 -> 5};

jerks = {jer1, jer2};
boundaries = {t < duration1, t < duration1 + duration2};

jer = Piecewise[Transpose[{jerks, boundaries}]]
acc1 = Integrate[jer /. t -> $t, {$t, 0, t}, 
    Assumptions -> {t \[Element] Reals}] // Simplify;
acc2 = DSolveValue[{y'[t] == jer, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t] // Simplify;
Print["Original: ", jer];
Print["Integrate gives: ", acc1];
Print["DSolveValue gives: ", acc2];
domain = {t, 0, duration1 + duration2} /. constants;
Plot[jer /. constants, domain, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[acc1 /. constants, domain, PlotRange -> Full]
Plot[acc2 /. constants, domain, PlotRange -> Full]
```

The expressions created in `acc1` and `acc2` are much more complicated than I would expect.  Any idea why neither of these functions yield a simple "Piecewise" function like the input?  The complexity ends up mattering as I integrate to get velocity and position Mathematica gets bogged down and isn't able to get an answer in a reasonable amount of time.

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look that complicated to me, it's just covering all the cases. Try adding more assumptions, like `duration1 > 0 && duration2 > 0`, that shortens it somewhat.

Comment: Oh, strange, I got rid of those assumptions when simplifying the problem for posting, but I guess this means more assumptions would be helpful.  In particular if I add the assumption t < duration1+duration2, then it simplifies to be as simple as the original formula being integrated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide everything you know about the problem and use that information at all opportunities. For example, presumably `duration1` and `duration2` are positive. If so, this needs to be included in the assumptions. And the assumptions need to be provided to all functions that accept the option `Assumptions`. The `Assuming` construct makes this easier.

```
jer1 = Sin[(Pi*t)/duration1];
jer2 = 1;
constants = {duration1 -> 6, duration2 -> 5};

jerks = {jer1, jer2};
```

Presumably, you do not want the function undefined at `t == duration1`, change `boundaries` to

```
boundaries = {t < duration1, t <= duration1 + duration2};

jer = Piecewise[Transpose[{jerks, boundaries}]];

acc1 = Assuming[
  {t ∈ Reals, duration1 > 0, duration2 > 0},
  Integrate[jer /. t -> $t, {$t, 0, t}] //
   FullSimplify]
```

[image]

```
acc2 = Assuming[
  {t ∈ Reals, duration1 > 0, duration2 > 0},
  DSolveValue[{y'[t] == jer, y[0] == 0}, y[t], t] //
   FullSimplify]
```

[image]